# Why does HTML/Django template execute code out of order?

Tags: python, html, django

This html template from my online class executes as intended, but why? It seems like it is executing out of order:

- It calls my python form class using Django's syntax {{form}} to inject the blank fields for the user to fill out (name, email, textbox)
- The user can enter and hit the "Submit" button
- but then (confusingly) is that it seems the {{form}} class is called *again* with the entry information as it then successfully prints out user input to the terminal. Why is this?

html in templates.py

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>fill out the form</h1>
        <div class="container"> 
            <form method="POST"> 
                {{form}} 
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submitme">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Form class in views.py

```
def form_name_view(request):
    form = forms.FormName() 
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = forms.FormName(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            print("VALIDATION SUCCESS")
            print("NAME: " + form.cleaned_data['name'])
            print("EMAIL: " + form.cleaned_data['email'])
            print("TEXT: " + form.cleaned_data['text'])

    return render(request, 'first_app/form_page.html', {'form' : form})
```

Supplemental: the url that uses the html template and my forms class

```
from django.urls import path
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [path('formpg', views.form_name_view, name = 'formpg')]
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what the question is.

Comment: The {{form}} generates blank fields, the user fills out the fields and hits submit provided by the <input...> button, then {{form}} seems to be executed again which prints out the fields to the terminal. The question is how is form being executed again to print out the user entries?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [Django form docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/#the-view),

> Form data sent back to a Django website is processed by a view, generally the same view which published the form. This allows us to reuse some of the same logic.

So your code is executing in the correct order:

1. When the page is first loaded, a GET request is made and `form_name_view()` is called. This creates an empty Form object and renders it into a html form with `render(request, 'first_app/form_page.html', {'form' : form})`
2. When the html form is submitted, a POST request is made and a new Form object is made with the data sent from the web browser. As in the example, you may want to direct users to another page if their submitted form is valid.

Comment: Bingo! Ok, so I guess hitting the submit button somehow automatically re-executed the view (and thus form class) with the new post request. If you have anymore explanation into what exactly happens to allow this, I would be curious.

Comment: If you use Right-click -> View Source or "Developer Mode" or similar to view your web page html, you will see that the form tag looks something like ``<form action="/form_page.html...>`. This means that clicking the submit button tells the web browser to make a new request to the web server, sending the form data to /form_page.html.